# odoo multiple measures together in line graph

Tags: graph, odoo, odoo-8

For my model with the following fields:

```py
name = fields.Char()
date = fields.Date()
value1 = fields.Float()
value2 = fields.Float()
```

I am trying to show multiple lines in the same graph this way:

```xml
<graph string="Results" type="line">
    <field name="date" type="row" interval="day"/>
    <field name="value1" type="measure" operator="+"/>
    <field name="value2" type="measure" operator="+"/>
</graph>
```

But it shows only one line. Every time I have to select the measure I want to see and deselect the other, while I need to see both at the same time.

The only way I was able to show the two values separately at the same time, is through a bar graph grouped by `name` field, but it is not what I need (I still had to show only one measure but at least I could achieve to have different colors for each group).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I did it:

```xml
<graph string="Results" type="line">
    <field name="date" type="row" interval="day"/>
    <field name="name" type="col"/>
    <field name="value1" type="measure" operator="+"/>
</graph>
```

I just need to put all values into `value1` and separate them by using `name`, obtaining different lines with same `name`

Comment: How did you manage that? Can we have a bit more info + python code? It seems so dark and mysterious...